# Focussing in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm developing an application using java swing. When I click a button, I want another window to be opened. This works fine. But it is possible to alt+tab to the original window and then interact with it even after the new window is open. Is there any way not to let the user focus the original window after the new window appears? By window I'm referring to Jframe/Jdialog.

Comment: Open a `JDialog` (as the second window) instead of a `JFrame` and pass the instance of your `JFrame` to the constructor of the `JDialog`

Comment: Then show us your code. A modal JDialog will definitely prevent focusing the parent window.

Comment: I don't think I can do that. I'm using netbeans editor to drag drop items. It simply won't let me modify the generated code.

Comment: NetBeans doesn't generate code that "opens another window". And most of the generated code *can* be modified by you using the properties of the components.

Comment: I just called the constructor again from an editable portion. Solved :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean "with call the constructor **again**" but most probably you are doing something wrong (especially if you are really calling it twice). Again: you *can* customize the generated code - use the "Code" tab in the properties window of the component.

Comment: there was already a dialog=new javax.swing.Jdialog() among the generated code. I just wrote the same line with the instance and the boolean value as the arguments in a function that handles button mouse clicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the instance of your main `JFrame` window is called `mainWindow`:, the following code will prevent switching the focus.

```
// the second parameter makes the dialog modal and will prevent
// switching the focus to the mainWindow
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(mainWindow, true);
...
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Documentation on JDialog: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html

Comment: Didn't work the first time because I didn't pass the boolean value true. Works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use a `JDialog`  instead of `JFrame` and pass the instance of `JFrame` to `JDialog` constructor

You may also try to check

```
 frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

or may be like this:-

```
frame.toFront();
frame.setState(Frame.NORMAL);
```